# The distance from an invertible matrix to the ill posed manifold

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking a class in numerical linear algebra and today the professor gave us the following result without proof. If A is an invertible n by n matrix, and $$
M = \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: X\text{ is singular}\}$$
i.e. the ill posed manifold, then
$$
\operatorname{dist}(A, M) = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.
$$
In particular, he said this is true for arbitrary norms in general. I can readily see a proof for this in the case of the spectral norm using the Eckart-Young theorem. However, for the Frobenius norm, also by the Eckart-Young theorem, I find that $\operatorname{dist}(A, M)$ is, as in the spectral norm case, equal to the minimum singular value of A. But here, wouldn't $\|A^{-1}\|_F$ be the harmonic mean of the singular values and so the result doesn't hold?